# $f(x)$ is non-negative and that $ \int_{-a}^b xf(x) dx = 0 $. Show $ \int_{-a}^bx^2f(x)dx \leq ab\int_{-a}^b f(x)dx $

Tags: real-analysis

$a, b > 0$. $f(x)$ is non-negative and integrable on $[-a, b]$ and that $ \int_{-a}^b xf(x) dx = 0 $. Prove that $$ \int_{-a}^bx^2f(x)dx \leq ab\int_{-a}^b f(x) dx $$
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry that's a typo! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This follows from $x^2\leq (b-a)x+ ab$ on $[-a,b]$.